# Load content_script.js when ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a test Chrome Extension which runs on `<all_urls>`.
It runs a content_script which just writes the domain.

It works fine in all cases, except when I write domains that do no exist.

The purpose of the Extension is to run on a particular domain, regardless of what it happens. Hence,  I want to make sure that it runs when I hit `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` too.

Any ideas on how to achieve it?

---

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ]

}
```

content_script.js

```
window.console.log(window.document.location.hostname);
```

Comment: Not possible. The page in this state doesn't support running content scripts.

Comment: I have found that it might be possible to achieve something similar with webRequest, but not sure if it would be possible without a domain resolved in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that you're trying to visit a non-existent domain, you're shown a Chrome internal error page with a `data:` URL.

This is not a valid match *even* for `<all_urls>`, so you can never inject into such pages.

If you need to capture navigation failures, you can do so via `webNavigation` or `webRequest` APIs from a background page; but you won't be able to modify the error pages.

Comment: Gave you the valid answer as it's the summary. I complemented with my answer anyway in case someone wants a more hands-on answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer:

While content_script is not possible, you can interact with the request with [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) and make changes to it. This fulfils my needs.

There are some examples on [Chrome Developer documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:webrequest). Otherwise, this is my new code:

---

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Lazy ShortCuts",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
  ]

}
```

background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(info) {
    console.log("Data intercepted: ", info);
    return {redirectUrl: 'https://google.com'};
  },
  {
    urls: [
      "<all_urls>",
    ]
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```